# ActiveMQ: How do I increase the maximum text message size in v5.14.5?

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic

Update: The `maxTextMessageSize` parameter seems to have been fixed in version `5.15.0`.  Thank you ActiveMQ team!

---

I am upgrading my project from ActiveMQ `5.8.0` to `5.14.5`.

We pass some moderately large messages over the websocket, so we have configured the websocket to accept large messages like so:

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:24511?websocket.maxTextMessageSize=9999999"/>
```

That worked great in v5.8.0, but doesn't appear to work in v5.14.5.  (I get the following error when I send a message):

[image]

How can I increase the maximum text message size in v5.14.5?

---

Related note: I tried reducing the `maxWebSocketFrameSize` in my stomp.js browser client, to see if breaking the message up would lead to better results in ActiveMQ.  However, when I did that, ActiveMQ then gave me the error:

[image]

Comment: After some investigation, it appears that the above `maxTextMessageSize` config works fine in v5.12.3, but does not in v5.13.5.